# How to iterate all the elements within a list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm new to the scene so just trying to learn basic concepts.

Can someone give me an example of how to iterate this list as an inner for loop? or any loop that seems appropriate.

So lets say I have...
myList = [1, 4, 9, 3]

how do I take in the index as an inner for loop so I can iterate over the numbers within a list?

for item in myList:
what do I do here? cause I can't seem to find a way to do this with the docs.

So for example, when the code runs, it'll run 1, 1 time, 4, 4 times, 9 9 times etc. in the inner loop

thanks for any info, hope this is clear anyways.

Please no flaming, I'm new to this and if there's a better solution with another data structure, please enlighten me.

Nothing yet, cause I'm not sure how you structure it (lack of knowledge)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
myList = [1, 4, 9, 3]
for x in myList:   
    for y in range(x):
        print(y)
```

Tested on [Fiddle](http://pythonfiddle.com/)